# Incorrect movie Keys metadata with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video, metadata

It seems ffmpeg erroneously copies keys metadata to UserData atom, and macOS 14 QuickTime player or Photos do not read it.

For example: The `input.mov` has Keys tags for Author, Title, Description, Keywords, GPS, date that macOS 14 QuickTime player and Photos display:

```
exiftool -a -G1 -s -n -Keys:All input.mov
[Keys]          Author                          : Author
[Keys]          Description                     : Description
[Keys]          Keywords                        : Keyword 1,Keyword 2
[Keys]          UserRating                      : 3
[Keys]          Title                           : Title
[Keys]          GPSCoordinates                  : -36.6101 -66.91515 119.9
[Keys]          CreationDate                    : 2001:01:01 12:00:00+02:00
```

Then re-encode it to `.MP4` with ffmpeg with options that *should* preserve metadata:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -c:v libx265 -tag:v hvc1 -c:a aac -movflags use_metadata_tags -map_metadata 0 output.mp4
```

But QuickTime player and Photos no longer display those tags in the `output.mp4`.

A workaround is to use exiftool to fix bad keys metadata with:

```
exiftool -m -overwrite_original -api LargeFileSupport=1 -Keys:All= -tagsFromFile @ -Keys:All output.mp4
```

https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=15418.msg82847#msg82847

So it seems ffmpeg '-movflags use_metadata_tags' incorrectly copies those Keys, and '-map_metadata 0' only preserves 'QuickTime:CreateDate'.

Question: Is there an option to correctly preserve Keys metadata in .mp4, .m4v and .mov with ffmpeg?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Maybe you can write it in a question and answer format where you write both? This is a Q&A site and self-answering questions is encouraged (FYIs not so much I believe). You can then accept your own answer.